# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' [React Native] [Android]

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I'm using a library - `react-native-dynamic-fonts` and when running it in Android Studio, it's giving me the below error as shown in screenshot.

[image]

And below screenshot shows details of my Android setup -

[image]

Library I'm using in my react-native Project - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dynamic-fonts